# node js segfault in Buffer javascript code

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js, buffer

my node app is crashing pretty much randomly when handling large amount of packets in a node extension. When I open the dropped core file in gdb (node compiled with debugging symbols) this is what I get:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x5e02190a in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x5e02190a in ?? ()
#1  0x5e01316a in ?? ()
#2  0x08210303 in v8::internal::Invoke(bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>,     v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*, bool*) ()
#3  0x0821062f in v8::internal::Execution::New(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*, bool*) ()
#4  0x081bfadd in v8::Function::NewInstance(int, v8::Handle<v8::Value>*) const ()
...
```

Looking at the source code of my C packet handling extension the NewInstance is actually a call to node's Buffer Constructor. Here is the offending fragment of the code (packet is a regular c data structure):

```
...
v8::Local<v8::Function> bufferConstructor = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(globalObj->Get(v8::String::New("Buffer")));
v8::Handle<v8::Value> constructorArgs[3] = { slowBuf->handle_, v8::Integer::New(packet->packet->dataLength), v8::Integer::New(0) };
v8::Local<v8::Object> actualBuffer = bufferConstructor->NewInstance(3, constructorArgs);
```

Now if I understand it correctly, Buffer source code is actually pure JS.

What could be the strategy to figure out where exactly in the JS code is this code crashing and why?

The code is running stable for days handling thousands of packets at the C level and turning them into node Buffer objects, it just crashes always with the same signature from time to time and I'd like to understand why...

Comment: What version of `node` are you on? Not familiar with passing 3 arguments to the `Buffer` constructor like that. That said, segfaults are dangerous, so it is also possible code somewhere else is corrupting something and making it crash later.